# VBA Excel; Finding Duplicate Cells and Populating an Offset Cell

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I am creating an automated system that reads data wirelessly transmitted data into excel. The data sends a gauge number and a value ex. 89,-.002 (gauge #89, value=-.002). This data goes into cell F2. I have already created code that separates the the gauge number and value into variables. I have a list of fixed gauge numbers in cell C5-C11 and the readings populate by offset in cells G5-G11 based on the gauge number. What I haven't been able to figure out is how to take the readings with the same gauge but multiple reading if we needed to check multiple spots on a part. So for example if there were three different readings needed for gauge 87 ( 87 would be listed three times in C5-C11), I need the code to search for the 87 based off my gauge number variable from the input in F2 and find all the 87's in cells C5-C11. Then check if the cell offset 4 columns has a value already. If it does then move on to the next 87 that was found and check if the offset on that one has a value. If it doesn't then populate the cell.

I can't hard code numbers in because it I am creating the template. So it would have to search for multiples with all the gauge numbers I believe.

Any help or ideas are appreciated. Even better if someone can give me sample code to integrate into my project.

Set wsInput = Sheet1
With wsInput.Range("C5:C24") 'selects sheet 1 range

```
Dim C As Range
Dim GageNum As String
Dim reading As String
Dim MyString As String
Dim Stringlen As Single
Dim location As Single
Dim GLOC As Single
Dim Count As Single
Dim Answer As Integer
Dim Count1 As Single
Dim i As Single

MyString = Range("F2").value 'identifies that cell data in F2 as a string variable
location = InStr(MyString, ",") + 1 'finds the comma separator and adds one to not include comma
GLOC = InStr(MyString, ",") - 1 'finds the location of the comma and goes back one to get rid of the comma.
'MsgBox location 'tests to see what character it is starting at
Stringlen = Len(MyString) - location + 1 'creates a new string that has the length of remaining characters
reading = Mid(MyString, location, Stringlen) 'reads string after the comma until the end of the string
'MsgBox Reading 'test to see if it gets the correct reading from gauage

GageNum = Left(MyString, GLOC) 'finds the gauge number by searching left of the comma
'MsgBox GageNum 'test of the guage number
Set C = .Find(GageNum, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not C Is Nothing Then
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim Rslt As String
    FirstAddress = C.Address
    Do
        Rslt = Rslt & C.Address & ","
       Set C = .FindNext(C)
Loop While C.Address <> FirstAddress
    'MsgBox Left(Rslt, Len(Rslt) - 1)
    End If
    End With

If Len(C.Offset(, 4)) = 0 Then
    Range("F2").Select
    C.Offset(, 4) = reading 'populates the cell with the reading.

Else
    Answer = MsgBox("Error: Gauge " & C & " measurement has already been taken." & vbNewLine & "Do you want to use this new measurement instead?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Re-measure?")
        If Answer = vbYes Then
            Range("F2").Select
            C.Offset(, 4) = reading 'populates the cell with the reading.
        Else
            'do nothing
        End If
End If
```

Thats what I have now but it doesnt search for duplicates I only get the first one that it finds.

Comment: When it populates the data, it's going from F2, then F3, then F4, right?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. I have it only populating F2 every time. So the way I have it is it enters to F3 so the intersect function works when we get off F2 and the data sorts into gauge number and value then it needs to search for the gauge numbers in C5-C11 and then offset the value then I have it automatically selecting F2 again.

Comment: How do you have it finding the gauge in C5-C11? Could you edit your post to include your code?

Comment: @PermaNoob I am working remotely right now. I don't have the code at the moment but I can edit my post tomorrow morning to include the code.

Comment: Alright. I'll take a look in the morning.

Comment: @PermaNoob I edited my post to include the code I'm using at the moment. Still need to find a way to fill the duplicate's field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with your `DO...LOOP WHILE` section. By putting the `While` condition at the end like that, you're telling it to continue looping UNTIL `C.Address = FirstAddress`. Instead of automatically setting C to the next one here: `Set C = .FindNext(C)`, you should test it first to determine whether the `FindNext` gives you the address you want. Something like this:

```
Set TempC = .FindNext(C)
If TempC.Address <> FirstAddress Then
    Set C = TempC
Else
    Exit Do
End If
```

NOTE: This will always set `C` to the last place the gauge number appears, not the very next one. To get the very next one, you could replace `FindNext` with `FindPrevious`. It would then loop in reverse order and wind up at the second instance of the gauge number.